# Dynamic address relocation of C++ objects

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management

I'm wondering if it's possible to address a class with a dynamic base address as opposed to a static one. The basic idea is as follows:

Have an object A defined like so:

```
class A
{
    //member variables
    ...
    //non-virtual member functions
    ...
    //virtual methods
    virtual void foo(...);
    ...
};
```

This class *cannot* be instantiated as a stack object, and does not have a standard new operator.

Instead, the object has a placement new that takes the base address and offset into memory from the base address, and uses this to compute the absolute address for construction.

What I want to do is have the object be accessed in code as follows:

```
A* clsA=new(base,offset) A();
...
clsA->foo( ... );
```

where

```
(char*)clsA == (char*)(base+offset)
```

but additionally be able to do the following

```
base+=4;
...
clsA->foo( ... );
```

and still have this:

```
(char*)clsA == (char*)(base+offset)
```

hold true.

I have no idea if this is possible in C++. I do know it can be done in ASM (x86/amd64), but I'd like a solution with as much portability as possible (which I recognize will still be next to none, but its better than nothing). Any suggestions?

EDIT: 
So I guess I wasn't too clear about the problem I have. The idea is to allow for a dynamic object (one allocated on the heap) to be moved around in memory. Normally this wouldn't be a problem, but since the objects cannot be instantiated through stack memory then the only way to access the object is through a pointer to the memory underlying the object. When the array moves (in the example, by four bytes), the pointers loaned from the array are no longer valid and need to be updated. As this process would not only be lengthy, but consume more memory than I wish to, I would like to be able to have the classes recalculate their memory addresses on access, rather than storing a relocation table with an entry for each loaned pointer.

Some assembly that might represent this concept would be

```
;rax stores clsA 
mov rcx, rax 
shr rcx, 32 
mov DWORD PTR[rdx], rax 
lea rax, rdx+rcx 
push rax 
call foo
```

EDIT 2: As it so turns out, there is also a MSVC modifier for this exact type of behavior. __based declares a pointer relative to another pointer, so the underlying memory can be moved around and the pointer remains valid. The article is  [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a97k4e.aspx).

Comment: You need to explain what you want to happen after adding 4 to the base pointer. I'm at a loss as to what you expect, behavior-wise.

Comment: Your example code doesn't make much sense; you never reuse the `base` variable after incrementing it by 4. Additionally, `new` does give you a dynamic base address.  If you only have a placement `new` defined for the class (which is pretty weird) then you can manually make a dynamic one by doing a `malloc()` first and then passing that new memory location to the placement `new`. However, I am not sure if this is what the question is actually asking.

Comment: Are you trying to make an adapter that sits on top of an existing array element and provides some extra functions?  Then make it a normal stack-allocatable class that holds a pointer (or reference) to the data you want to wrap.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I edited the question to try and clarify the issue. It's a rather obscure problem and I'm not sure there's actually an answer in C++.

Comment: What does `base+=4` do?

Comment: Wait, when you say "the object's memory", do you mean "the memory where the object is" (like an int), or "the memory that the object _manages_", (like a vector's data).

Comment: I'm talking about the virtual address in the OS heap memory where the object data is stored (the value you might get with `ptrdiff_t ptr=(ptrdiff_t)clsA;`)

Comment: @Alex: Then yeah, what you're talking about makes no sense at all.  Sorry, we won't be able to answer your question until you can communicate what you want.  But I bet it's doable in C++.  Maybe you want something like this? http://ideone.com/AV40KZ

Comment: @Alex: Can you walk us through what you want in assembly on http://ideone.com/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you, what you need is *pointers* that are always relative to another pointer.  This is easy, but usually a bad idea.

```
template<class T>
struct reloc_ptr {
    template<class U>
    reloc_ptr(char*& base, int offset, U&& v) 
        :base(&base), offset(offset) 
    {new(get())T(std::forward<U>(v));}

    T* get() const {return (T*)(*base+offset);}
    T* operator->() const {return get();}
    void destroy() {get()->~T();}
private:
    char** base;
    int offset;
};
```

and then normal usage is like this

```
int main() {
    char* base = new char[1000];
    //construct
    reloc_ptr<A> clsA(base,4, "HI"); //I construct the A with the param "HI"
    //test
    clsA->foo();
    //cleanup
    clsA.destroy();
    delete[] base;
}
```

Note that the reloc_ptr is relative to the `char* base` that it was constructed from, so be *very very careful* with that.  If the `char* base` variable is in a function, and the function ends, then all pointers constructed with that `char* base` variable become invalid and using them will make the program do strange things.

http://ideone.com/4DNUGQ

Comment: This is what I was looking for. The memory block the objects reside in is managed by a custom memory allocator, but if it's resized, all of the pointers to the objects contained within the memory are still valid. Sorry, its a rather convoluted question, but I was stumped on how exactly to go about implementing it.

Comment: In general, allocators should _not_ move stuff.  That can invalidate a lot of code, like `std::map`, and friends.  Generally, allocators have something more akin to a container of memory regions.  When a region is full, they grab another region.  Do _NOT_ move stuff that was already allocated :(

Comment: Unfortunately, due to the nature of the allocators in question, they can't operate in that way, as they aren't doing a malloc style memory allocation. The memory managers utilize memory in either a stack or pool style, and when they run out of room, the OS determines if they can expand or not. I can't allocate a new block and tack it onto the end as that ruins the internal processing of the memory manager, and most often times I can't resize the block in place as the operating system has things in the way. So, I needed a solution to keep one, contiguous memory block that can still be resized.

Answer (score 1):

Something very similar to what you are asking is the [placement new syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax) of C++.

> Placement new is used when you do not want operator new to allocate memory (you have pre-allocated it and you want to place the object there), but you do want the object to be constructed.

In your example you might allocate a class A on a particular location in memory in order to then apply method foo() to it.

```
void* memoryBuffer;
...
unsigned int i = 0;
for (uint i= 0; i < N; i += offsetSize){
   //initialize a given a specific location in memoryBuffer
   A* a = new(memoryBuffer + i)A(...); 

   //apply foo on that specific memory  location
   a->foo();
}
```

This is what appens for instance using [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TutorialMapClass.html) to wrap a matrix object around a preallocated numerical buffer.

Comment: That's what I'm already doing. I want to be able to move the memory out from under the object, but have the object recognize that fact and update the pointer to it on access.

Comment: @Alex: If the object is moved from a memory location, then all the pointers will still be pointing at the old memory, and there is absolutely no way for those pointers to know where the new memory is.  This isn't a C++ problem, this is a basic logic problem, so it applies to assembly too.  Maybe you can explain what you mean with some assembly?

Comment: `;rax stores clsA`

`mov rcx, rax`

`shr rcx, 32`

`mov DWORD PTR[rdx], rax`
`lea rax, rdx+rcx`
`push rax`
`call foo`

The above assumes foo is a static function. It'll be a little different with a virtual function.

Comment: Basically you want to reuse the same instance of class A over different memory location.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about addressing the object of type `A *` at an offset position, an object someone else moved somehow, you'd use something like `(clsA+offset)->foo( ... )`, where `offset` is in `sizeof A` units, ie. your earlier `4` would actually be a `1` because you probably mean to move to the "next" adjacent object in memory.

If you're talking about actually moving the object, you can placement-`new` at the new address in memory, then call the copy constructor (or `memcpy` for a POD), but this is pretty iffy depending on what your object holds, if it insists on ownership of pointers and when you call placement-`delete` that memory gets freed you're pretty SOL.

I can't emphasize this enough, tell us what you're trying to accomplish because there might be a better way, this is pretty against the proverbial grain right here.

Comment: The first is what I'd like to do, but without the additional address computation in the access. If I can hide away that detail, it would be ideal.

And the 4 is a byte offset - the idea of it being that no matter what `base` is, the expression `(char*)clsA == (char*)(base+offset)` will be true.